# ExpandableListView inside RecyclerView inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, android-recyclerview

I'm facing problems in scrolling. I've the following structure in order in my project:

1) ViewPager
2) RecyclerView
3) ExpandableListView

I cannot scroll the ExpandableListView; but I can scroll RecyclerView. I tried setNestedScrolling but i didn't work.

Any solutions?

Comment: so you have a scrollable view (ViewPager) that holds another scrollable view (RecyclerView) that holds yet another scrollable view (ExpandableListView) and you are surprised that you have problems with scrolling? just simplify your UI

Comment: I am not surprised pskink at all. Anyway, @Ammar solution was accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to do is disable the scroll of the parent when you touch the child. So this should work

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
       v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
       return false;
    }
});
```